# Double column value in a spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I need to double the value of a column (ex: C) into another (ex: F) for every row in a spreadsheet.
How can I achieve this?
This is probably simple, but I can't get my head around it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting `=2*C1` in F1 and copying the cell down the column.

Comment: Or put =C1+C1 in F1 and copy to all the cells below, till you have values in column C.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Google Spreadsheet (`F1`):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(C:C),"",(C:C * 2)))
```